# mongoose find document with combined fields with one search parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I am using Nodejs and Mongodb with Mongoose. My model contains following properties:

```
first_name
last_name
status
```

I need to use mongoose find functions to search users with these 3 fields. I have 2 parameters:

```
full_name: Craig de Zia
status: alive
```

For example, I have a name called Craig de Zia. I don't know which parts of the name are first name or last name, so I want to search FULL name. And I want to connect full name and status with "$and" logic. The condition structure would be like:

```
'$and': [ 
    { 'full_name': 'Craig de Zia' },
    { status: 'alive' },
]
```

The problem is that there is no **full_name** field in the database. We need to combine **first_name** field and **last_name** field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Manage **first_name** and **last_name** as per condition

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $expr: { $eq: ['Craig de Zia', { $concat: ["$first_name", "$last_name"] }] }
    },
    { 'status': 'alive' }
  ]
})
```

Please manage first_name and last_name here $concat as **"first_namelast_name"** and if you want to search
**first_name** and **last_name** with space in between them then use

`{ $concat: ["$first_name", " ", "$last_name"] }`

Comment: Thanks! It works! May I ask another question about regex? Can I also add this regex: $regex: new RegExp("\\b" + full_name, "i") so that it does not have to exactly match?

Comment: $or: [{ first_name: { $regex: /\bSearchingKeyWord/, $options: 'ig' } },{ last_name: { $regex: /\bSearchingKeyWord/, $options: 'ig' } }] you can do this but you can't find required result.